# Script to update users value in data base not working – issue with sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I’m pretty much a complete beginner when it comes to PHP and have been having some problems with my script to update the current users values in the database – when the script fires it doesn’t update the value in the database as intended at all.

Some background info:

Database name: “user”

Table “users” with columns User ID , Username , Password , Emailaddress , Offer.

Site that I’m working on allows users to complete a number of offers and then get rewarded upon completion. The offer column has the default value of “1”. Upon login the user is redirected according to the value in the offer column. (So on first login user is redirected to example.com/offer1 , after offer 1 is completed this value is updated so on next login user is redirected to offer 2 – in essence storing the users progress) This login process works fine , its just updating the value which is my problem.

This is the script which is played after an offer is completed (in this case after offer 3 is completed) – aim to connect to database and then update that users “offer” so when they next login they will be directed to the correct offer – thus storing their progress:

*~Could this actually not be a problem with the Script its self but in regards to sessions not starting/continuing correctly upon login – or maybe an issue with the script not using the session data correctly?~*

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","name","password","user");
$select = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT offer FROM user      WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'"));
$plus = $select['offer']++;
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET offer=3".$plus."where user_id = $id" );
header("location: http://example.com/offer4".$plus);
?>
```

The `mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET offer=3".$plus."where user_id = $id" );` isn't working at all, could the issue be here?

In case it helps , this is a previous version I was using *which did* work in updating the values but does so for *all users* in the database rather than just the one user who is logged in. So lets say Jim has completed this offer , his Offer value will be updates to 3 but so will all the other users will have their offer value set to 3 when only Jim’s should be.

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pass","user");
$select = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT offer FROM users      WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'"));
$plus = $select['offer']++;
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET offer=3".$plus);
header("location: http://example.com/offer4".$plus);
?>
```

Just for reference here is my login script – this works correctly in redirecting user upon login to value in their Offer column  (could my problem be to do with sessions not starting correctly?)

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>  
<body>  
<div id="main">
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
     $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

     $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
    {
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
        $email = $row['EmailAddress'];

        $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;

         echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
        echo "<p>We are now redirecting you to the member area.</p>";
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'\'" />'; 

    }
    else
    {
         echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
    }
}
else
{
    ?>

   <h1>Member Login</h1>

   <p>Thanks for visiting! Please either login below, or <a href="register.php">click here to register</a>.</p>

    <form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>

   <?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lastly, heres base.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$dbhost = "localhost"; // this will ususally be 'localhost', but can sometimes differ
$dbname = "user"; // the name of the database that you are going to use for this project
$dbuser = "name"; // the username that you created, or were given, to access your database
$dbpass = "password"; // the password that you created, or were given, to access your database

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
?>
```

Thank you very much for your time and have a good evening ; very much appreciate all the previous replies here that have been so helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION['Username'])) {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pass","user");

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['Username']);

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET Offer = Offer + 1 WHERE Username = '{$username}'");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $offer = $row['Offer'];
    }

    header("Location: http://example.com/offer".$offer);
} else {
    echo "You are not logged in.";
}
```

[`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) will escape dangerous characters from the username. You can use an [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) to increment a cell's value by an amount (in this case 1).

Another thing to note: In the `PHP` on the page with the `HTML`, you are using `mysql` extension functions instead of `mysqli`. The `mysql` extension is deprecated. Either way, your code is inconsistent in the use of `mysql` and `mysqli`. For a list of equivalent `mysqli` functions, check the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

You said your database was called `user` and your table `users`. In your first query statement, you selected `offer` from a table called `user` not `users`. You can use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to display errors, which you would have received.

Regarding your second `mysqli_query` statement:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET offer=3".$plus."where user_id = $id" );
```

There is no $id anywhere else in your code. Also you need a space before your `where`, otherwise if $plus == 13, the statement reads `SET offer=313where user_id...`.

According to your code (`$select['offer']++`), you retrieve the previous `offer` value, increment it by 1 and then set the `offer` value in the database to this incremented value with a 3 added on to the beginning.

If offer == 31, then after going through your code, the new offer == 332.

**EDIT:** Something else I just noticed. I think you are misunderstanding the `++` operator. When used after an operand, it is called the post-increment operator. When used before, it is called the pre-increment operator. The reason for this is because in the case of the post-increment operator, the value of the operand (in your case $select['offer']) is assigned to $plus before it is incremented. What this means, in the context of your code, is that you are never actually incrementing the offer value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and all the other pointers to sort out the code. Had a go at the script your kindly provided and it just comes up with a white page and offer value in DB not updated. Do you know what could be going wrong? :/

Comment: Is it possible `$_SESSION['Username']` is not set?

Comment: Yup that could be the problem , don't think i've set it. How could I do it? Got session_start(); in the base.php file but thats it so i'm not sure.  Would I need php session_start() any where else?       Again , thanks for the help!

Comment: Could be? Confirm it. After session_start() run `var_dump($_SESSION)`. You should be setting it in the index.php page with the line `$_SESSION['Username'] = $username`. Check for mysql errors using the mysql error function. Check for PHP errors by placing this at the beginning of your code: `ini_set('display_errors',1); ini_set('display_startup_errors',1); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Got it! :)  managed to use ini_set('display_errors',1); ini_set('display_startup_errors',1); error_reporting(-1); and found I was using the wrong case in first letter of my password. Feel so silly! Thanks for all the help though , much appreciated and your script worked great!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET offer=3".$plus."where user_id = $id" );
```

Where is $id coming from? In the line above, you used username.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is `"UPDATE users SET offer=3".$plus."where user_id = $id"`. In PHP with `$plus` variable equal, e.g. "54" this becomes "UPDATE users SET offer=354where user_id = $id". So, a space is missing before `where`.

If this is not the case, learn to use mysqli error logging: http://php.net//manual/ru/mysqli.error.php.